# Badge proposal: Semi-fanatic

Tags: discussion, badges, badge-request

I'd like to discuss proposal for having a badge, similar to *Fanatic*, awarded for people, who have visited particular SE site for five consecutive days (workdays, workweek) in 30 or 40 consecutive weeks.

Reasons:

1. Though many may find it surprising, *there are* people, who doesn't touch computers / tablets / doesn't visit Internet during weekends. For many, many reasons (resting, family, because they want so etc.). Does it makes them less fanatic to any SE site?
2. For me personally, a person, who visits site every one of five working days during every of following 30 or 40 weeks is far more fanatic to the site than the one, who visits it for 100 consecutive days.
3. I don't have proper knowledge of [Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/) to write a proper query and verify this, but I'm pretty sure, that there are many people, who had around 80-90 consecutive days of visits, didn't visited site for one single day and lost the all "effort".

Is this proposal reasonable, under above arguments?

Comment: "Does it makes them less fanatic to any SE site?" - Yes, I'd say that not wanting to visit the site on weekends *does* make them less of a fanatic, pretty much by definition.

Comment: @JonSkeet Does the fact, that they don't visit any site during weekends changes anything? Does the fact, that these theoretical people doesn't have computer / tablet / Internet access at home, and that's why they don't visit SE nor any other site during weekend / outside office changes anything?

Comment: I've attempted do get this badge twice... And failed both times around the 62 - 70 day spot, due to having to do some a sporting event both times, sometimes its just not possible due to our lives/situations outside of the coding community...

Comment: @RohanBüchner I don't even count, how many times I attempted to achieve this. But, Jon's comment suggest, that we're second-class users, because we're not enough fanatic! :]

Comment: Well, I do agree with him ITO definition. But there isn't a badge to meet some people mid-way at the moment... and TBH, its up to SO's discretion if they want to add one... which brings us back to your badge-request.. seems like a vicious circle.

Comment: @JonSkeet And then, again, it is not that we _don't want_ to visit site during weekend (or any other day). It is that life sometimes forbids us from doing so. I think, that finding myself visiting SE site during my child serious illness or during funeral, only to not loose "day streak" toward Fanatic badge, would make me fanatic in the very bad way.

Comment: Well, is it so bad not to have the badge? There are a lot of gold badges I'll never have, and I think I'll be just fine without them.

Comment: @RohanBüchner There is a badge to meet people mid-way. Enthusiast is a silver badge for 30 consecutive days.

Comment: @RetoKoradi It depends on, whether you like shiny gold coins shimmering to you every morning? :] But, seriously... this question is more like asking, isn't fair for those, who are _unable_ (not: _don't want_, as Jon suggests) to visit site _every_ 100 days, but visits it 200 or more days, with 1-2-3 days exception.

Comment: "But, Jon's comment suggest, that we're second-class users, because we're not enough fanatic!" No, it doesn't suggest that at all. I've suggested that someone who *does* put other things ahead of visiting the site isn't as fanatical as someone who doesn't. That is in *no way* indicating that being fanatical should be seen as a good thing, or change powers etc. It's a badge - it's *just* a badge. Note that your original post uses "resting, family, because they want so [sic - I assume you mean to rather than so?]" - that's not "unable" to visit. If you meant "unable" you should have said so.

Comment: @JonSkeet Thanks for clearing this out. My comment, you cite, was a joke, of course (thus simily at the end). I see your points and I agree with that. As good as with fact, that people can have different points of view on my proposal.

Comment: Some people don't log in on weekends for religious reasons. Due to my time zone, i am able to make it each UTC day, but others can't. Support.

Comment: As a *true* fanatic, I wear my badge proudly! Catering to the casuals? I say no!

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79995/get-rid-of-the-consecutive-days-requirement

Comment: I completely agree with Jon though. There is nothing wrong at all with not having a Fanatic badge.

Comment: I think it is unfair to have semi-fanatic, if we don't also have **quarter-fanatic**... and now that I think about it, we should also have **one-tenth-fanatic**, and maybe **infinitesimally-small-faction-fanatic**.

Comment: @Louis, all jokes aside, working inside the confines of the existing badge ranking system... Is it that unreasonable to imagine & request something that fits all 3 badge tiers?

Comment: If they *only* visit the site during work hours then perhaps the badge name should be skiver.

Comment: @Scimonster people who don't log in on weekends for religious reasons have their own fanatic badge.

Comment: Funny that this suggestion is downvoted on meta.SO (currently -11) and upvoted on meta.SE (http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274642/badge-proposal-semi-fanatic?rq=1 currently +23)  Perhaps SO users have a higher standard for fanaticism.

Comment: The Stack Exchange app really helps the true fanatics.

Answer (score -7):

As stated in my comments, I've also attempted to have a go at getting this badge with not as much success..

I think it could be potentially linked to the fact that the rating scale is skewed somewhat at the moment, not broken skewed, as it was created as is at the moment for a reason... but skewed in terms of how we'd divide the max day requirement (100) of the highest value badge, into values that will fit the other 2 badge types.

> 100 / 3 = 33.3 days per badge level

How the system currently works

- bronze     ->   silver -> gold
- (nothing)  ->   30     -> 100

30 for a silver, and 100 for a gold. Not really half way... And from an achievement level, to me at least, its too easy to get to what I'd perceive as a middle tier achievement, thus lessening the value of the badge. If we re-calibrate the reward process, those of us who are "semi-fanatic"... might be happier to have a silver badge.

A simple change if anything could meet everyone halfway:

1. 30 days (1 month) - Bronze
2. 60 days (2 months) - Silver
3. 90 days (100 days) (3 months) - Gold

Comment: the scale is not skewed.. compare CopyEditor: 1 -> 80 -> 500 edits... that's .. a slight difference and "skewed scale" It's just not linear (and IMO shouldn't be)

Comment: @Vogel612 I mean it's all opinion based anyway. My answer was just my take on it. ITO, Copy Editor, there are 3 tiers... Where as Fanatic, there's only 2, so it could be seen as skewer (ratios aside). I do get that all the Badge types don't have a badge in all the levels, but again. Just a possible solution to the OP's problem.

Comment: How can one fail this badge when they specifically attempt to get it? Especially now that views via the mobile apps also count towards the days visited. You have to visit the SO homepage or open the SO app _once_ per UTC day, which takes way less than a minute of your time. Let's say you boot a pc specifically for visiting SO - even that takes less than 5 minutes. Of course one can _forget_ this easily, but it's by no means hard for anybody who owns a pc and a smart phone. The only reason I can think of is travelling and not having any internet access for more than 24 hours.

Comment: @l4mpi: Agreed, this way I am now on day 94/100... Fingers crossed for the last 6 days :-)

Comment: @l4mpi, so my answer wasn't geared toward the "failing" of getting this badge... If someone was that strung up on getting it, they could always setup a VM and a script to automatically log in once every day for a 100 days... I just meant that if we had another middle tier goal/checkpoint to reach, it might act as incentive to actually visit more often... you know smaller achievable goals. Whoa... that sounds a lot like SCRUM :/

Comment: @l4mpi people not always have mobile internet. But those are not real fanatics. Fanatics don't go where there's no internet.